# vue & vitest, data-v-[random-number] attribute being added to html

Tags: vuejs3, vite, vitest

**Introduction**: I am working with vite and vitest, I am doing snapshot tests for components that are 100% template and do not contain any logic

**Problem**: data-v-[random-number] It is being added to the root element of each component and snapshots are always different

**What i want**: Understand why im getting this data-v-[random-number] and if possible, a way to avoid this problem

**Short example code:**

BaseText.vue:

```
<script setup lang="ts"></script>
<template>
    <span><slot></slot></span>
</template>
```

BaseText.spec.ts:

```
import { describe, it, expect } from "vitest";
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import BaseText from "./BaseText.vue";

describe(name, () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(BaseText);
    it("MatchSnapshot", () => {
        expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

Error when runing tests:

```
 - Expected   ""<span data-v-25e5131c=""></span>""
  + Received   ""<span data-v-b3462088=""></span>""
```

Comment: data-v-[random-number] is generated because you have <style scoped> in your component, maybe you can try expect(wrapper.element).toMatchSnapshot() and just update your snapshot, the random-number stays the same in my case

Comment: @MgsMRizqiFadhlurrahman Hello, thanks for your reply, but this component has no <style> tag and its happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this library to remove the `data-v` attributes (does it automatically). It also covers many many other common things you'd need when using Snapshot testing with Vue.

- https://github.com/tjw-lint/jest-serializer-vue-tjw/#using-with-vitest

Despite having `jest` in the name, this works with Vitest as well.